# How to demostrate Sub-set from flat is a open set

Tags: calculus

The set `C={(x,y);2< x^2 + y^2 < 4}`

How can we defined this set as open using the **definition**.

Comment: ????????? You can't honestly think that is a comprehensible question, can you?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What definition of open are you using and what are you trying?  Try Picking a point (a,b) in C.  Then 2 < a^2 + b^2 < 4.  Can you find an open  neighbor around (a,b) in which all the points are in C?  In other which every (x,y) in the neighbor 2 < x^2 + y^2 < 4?  How close to (a,b) do (x,y) have to be for that to be true?  Can you draw pictures?

Answer (score 1):

This is an annulus in the plane. You want to show that it is open directly from the definition. Therefore, it is enough to show that around any point of the annulus, you can find an open disk containing the point which is wholly contained in the annulus. I will explain a procedure for finding such a disk. The details are left to you.

Pick $p \in C$. We can parameterize $C$ in polar coordinates, and then easily draw the normal line from $p$ to the boundary of $C$, since the polar coordinates tell us the angle of the line through the origin that $p$ lies on. Then the distance along this line from $p$ to either the inside or the outside boundary of $C$ is the minimal distance from $p$ to the boundary. Take half the minimum of these two values. The result is a disk which is guaranteed to be contained in $C$. Since $p$ is arbitrary, every point of $C$ is an interior point, and $C$ is open.

The proof relies on the fact that the definition of $C$ uses $<$ and not $\leq$, as otherwise those values could possibly be $0$, in which case the above method does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b) \in C $

$2 < a^2 + b^2 < 4$

Let $M = \min (4 - (a^2+b^2), (a^2 + b^2) -2) $

Let $\epsilon = \sqrt { M}/2$.

Let $N =\{(x,y)| d( (x,y), (a,b)) < \epsilon $i.e $|\sqrt {(x-a)^2 - (y-b)^2} < \epsilon\} $

Let $(w,z) \in N$.....

To be continued.....